# Date is showing Null in Column

Tags: angularjs

I have `cmdate` filter for showing date in ng-rpeat.

But `ng-repeat` showing null in date column

**Filter**

```
app.filter('cmdate', [
  '$filter', function ($filter) {
      return function (input, format) {
          return $filter('date')(new Date(input), format);
      };
   }
]);
```

**MarkUp**

```
<tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="o in CustomerCarePreviousFeedBack">
        <td>{{o.Date | cmdate:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
        <td>{{o.FeedBackDetail}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: what do you have in `o.Date` ? milli seconds?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any custom filter for this

Because this line `$filter('date')(new Date(input), format);` itself can do what you want.

Just call this line  `$filter('date')(new Date(input), format);` as it is a  default angular filter

So just try do change `cmdate` to `date`, Like

```
<tbody>
 <tr data-ng-repeat="o in CustomerCarePreviousFeedBack">
 <td>{{o.Date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
<td>{{o.FeedBackDetail}}</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
```

More details please read from this below documents

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

http://www.angulartutorial.net/2014/04/date-filtering-and-formatting-in.html

Comment: /Date(1441350000000)/ now the result is.

Comment: after apply <td>{{o.Date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>

Comment: @RanaAli this is the https://fiddle.jshell.net/ , here you can put your working code sample, helpers can see your real scenario and help you out.

Answer (score 0):

As Ramesh Rajendran said their is built in filter called date, but in case you need to write your own custom one check the following it's working fine.

```js
app = angular.module('myModule', []);

app.controller('MyController', ['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.CustomerCarePreviousFeedBack = [{
      Date: new Date(),
      FeedBackDetail: "FeedBack Details"
    }];
}]);

app.filter('cmdate', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return function(input, format) {
      return $filter('date')(new Date(input), format);
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="MyController">

  <table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="o in CustomerCarePreviousFeedBack">
      <td>{{ o.Date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
      <td>{{o.FeedBackDetail}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```